# I'm getting this error : Traceback (most recent call last): File "./prog.py", line 4, in <module> KeyError: 'price'

Tags: python, windows, list, error-handling, python-3.7

```
prices = ['31', '32']
txt = "For only {price:.2f} dollars!"
for i in prices:
    print(txt.format(prices))
```

Im trying this to get :
For only 31.00 dollars
For only 32.00 dollars but am facing this issue. Please help, Im a noob

```
prices = ['31', '32']
txt = "For only {price:.2f} dollars!"
for i in prices:
    print(txt.format(prices))
```

Comment: [Here is a example of formating](https://stackoverflow.com/a/455634/5990202). In your example `price` is unknown command/variable to python

Answer (score 0):

You were about 80% there.
Try the following code:

#### Code:

```
prices = ['31', '32']

for i in prices:
    print(f"For only {int(i):.2f} dollars!")
```

#### Output:

```
For only 31.00 dollars!
For only 32.00 dollars!
```